# Regex Text Field Validator for iPhone

Tags: iphone, regex, qt, validation

I have the following behavior of a desktop version of a software:

- a text field is validated with a regex `abc|xyz`
- this means that a user is allowed to type `a`, `ab`, `x`, `xy`, `abc`, `xyz`, other symbols will not be shown in a text field

I have to port such behavior to iphone.
Strings `a`, `ab`, `x`, `xy` does not match to regex `abc|xyz` that's why matching user input will restrict typing any char to a text filed. **Is there any way to match a user input as a beginning of a regex string?** Initial regex should not be modified (^$ could be added).

The desktop version uses [QRegExpValidator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qregexpvalidator.html) class from Qt. QRegExpValidator has *Intermediate* state that is `a`, `ab`, `x`, `xy` in my case. It [uses](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/widgets/qvalidator.cpp#line894) matchedLength() to determine *Intermediate* state

Also I had a look through [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. It is rumored to be used in Apple products.